# How to print report in marathi language using resource files C#

Tags: c#, wpf, report

How can i convert dynamic text from english to marathi that i want to display on report using C# code , without any third party translators.i already i have list of marathi and english texts

```
Assembly assembly = this.GetType().Assembly;
ResourceManager resourceManager = new ResourceManager("Resources.Strings", assembly);
string myString = resourceManager.GetString("value");
```

Comment: This will help you https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/65794e/how-to-read-resx-file-in-c-sharp/

Comment: So the main takeaway is to use the [GetString](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager.getstring) overload that accepts a certain `CultureInfo` and then provide the one that is wanted.